# How can I validate the value of @RequestQuery

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to validate the value of the query param below after the equals sign in the REST URI, does anyone know how to do it with Spring 4.1 please?

I want to validate in the method parameters that 'drive' is the passed param but all I can validate is the operation part

I would like to do something like `@RequestParam(value = "drive")`

localhost/test?operation=drive

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> operation(@RequestParam(value = "operation", required = true) String operation)
```

`

Comment: Can you please clarify the following? _I want to validate in the method parameters that 'drive' is the passed param but all I can validate is the operation part_

Comment: In the Method body you could use something like this:
`if ("drive".equals(operation)) {
    doSomethingSpecial();
}`
But you should clarify your question a bit.

Comment: I want to validate in the method parenthesis and not use an if in the method body

Comment: I want to do this @RequestParam(value = "drive")

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) [annotations](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html).

If you want to check if the value is allowed, you can use [`@Pattern`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) with a regular expression:

```java
@Pattern(regexp = "value1|value2|value3", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> operation(
    @RequestParam(value = "operation", required = true)
    @Pattern(regexp = "value1|value2|value3", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    String operation) {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: This still goes into the method body, how can I make it fail without returning from code?

Comment: @M_K What do you mean with _this still goes into the method body_?

Comment: if I use '@RequestParam(value = "operation", required = true) @Pattern(regexp = "drive" , flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE) String operation' it completes the url for the test?operation=incorrect and does not fail, it should fail

Comment: @M_K Once you have Bean Validation working, the validation will fail and the method won't be executed.

Comment: can you please clarify 'Once you have Bean Validation working'

Comment: @M_K Check this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) from Baeldung about Bean Validation with Spring.

Comment: I was eventually able to validate the params through '@RequestMapping(value = "/test", params="operation=drive" method = RequestMethod.PUT)'   this was the only way I could find that validates that I have 'operation' and 'drive' in the query params